# How to let React web app to run on both http and https?

Tags: reactjs, http, https, server, port

I can visit http.
I have tried many ways to let it run on port 443 (which will be https)
However, I failed. The browser message is
This site can’t provide a secure connection(uses an unsupported protocol)  ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH

Following is my trail.

I use next js for routing.

```
const {createServer}=require('http')
const createServer2=require('https')
const next=require('next');
const app=next({
    dev:process.env.NODE_ENV !=='production'
});
const routes=require('./routes')
const handler = routes.getRequestHandler(app);
app.prepare().then(()=>{
    createServer(handler).listen(80,(err)=>{
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('ready on port 80, you can visit http')
    })
    createServer2.createServer(handler).listen(443,(err)=>{
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('ready on port 443, you can visit https')
    })
})
```